# Blocky image with UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

I have a weird issue...

I have an image (a small thumbnail) included in the project AND as a file in the documents directory (both files are IDENTICAL)... when I load it into an image view using **[UIImage imageNamed:xxx]** it is perfect however when I load it into an image using **[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:xxx]** then it is really blocky....

Anyone have an idea why this would be... I repeat the images are identical (so it is not a different format or resolution which is the issue).

This is on the iPad, iOS 3.2

Comment: This question is so old it's probably left the rest home. But I just ran into what appears to be the same thing. In my case it's nothing to do with scale factors, and everything to do with `imageWithContentsOfFile:` returning a 34x34 image, even though the source image is ten times that (and a different aspect ratio). I'm smelling an iOS bug, but instead of hunting it down I just worked around it. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

`imageWithContentsOfFile:` loads from the specified file, but `imageNamed:` tries to find a double precision version first. So, if you have an image file xxx@2x, it will be loaded instead of xxx.